# Is it possible to build dynamic string type based on other custom string type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have prepared simple code to represent the issue. I have a type that accepts a bunch of string, let's called it Names:

```
type Names = "field1" | "field2";
```

Now I need to build a type that will accept also a bunch of new strings based on the `Names` type.

```
type Names = "field1" | "field2";

type FieldsNames =
  | "field1_created"
  | "field1_updated"
  | "field1_deleted"
  | "field2_created"
  | "field2_updated"
  | "field2_deleted";
```

As you can see, for each string (field1, field2) I need to build a type that accepts another three types of string. This already can grow really fast.

Is there a way to for example, extract keys from `Names` type and based on that, create new custom types? If so how to do it with typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```js
type Names = "field1" | "field2";

type Prefix = 'created' | 'updated' | 'deleted'

type FieldsNames =
    | "field1_created"
    | "field1_updated"
    | "field1_deleted"
    | "field2_created"
    | "field2_updated"
    | "field2_deleted";

type Builder<T extends string> = T extends any ? `${T}_${Prefix}` : never

// Result is the same as FieldsNames
type Result = Builder<Names>

type Assert<T, _ extends T> = T

type Test = Assert<Result, FieldsNames> // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0dJw)

`T extends any` - turns on distributivity

Comment: Thanks, works as expected!
Learnt something new ;)

Comment: Then I only needed to create a function to build string:
```
export const buildTopicFieldEventName = (
  name: Names,
  sufix: Sufix
): Result => {
  return `${name}_${sufix}` as Result;
};
```

Comment: @papryk if you want to concat two arguments, you don't need to use `type assertion`. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvKdrw)